# Invoke target inside ifeq/ifneq in another target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am new to writing Makefiles, is it common or "good practice" to invoke targets inside `ifeq` or `ifneq` from another target?

This is the original Makefile. I can run `my_test` by `make my_test`:

```
build : target1 target2
...
my_test : | prereq1 prereq2
    COMMAND_TO_RUN_MY_TEST
```

Now, I want to add a condition such that every time it builds, it checks the condition first and then decide whether or not to run the test:

```
build : target1 target2 run_check
...
my_test : | prereq1 prereq2
    COMMAND_TO_RUN_MY_TEST

OLD_VERSION := $(shell COMMAND_TO_RETRIEVE_THE_OLD_VERSION)
NEW_VERSION := $(shell COMMAND_TO_RETRIEVE_THE_NEW_VERSION)
run_check :
ifneq ($(NEW_VERSION), $(OLD_VERSION))
    echo "Version updated. Run test"
    $(MAKE) my_test
else
    echo "Same version. Skip test"
endif
```

This works but it feels unncessary calling another instance of make here. It does not look like any Makefile has logics like this from the examples I see. From my understanding, "target" is like a function. All I want to do is to call a function inside another function in an "if" statement. This feels normal in other languages but seems to be not so common in Makefile. Want to see if there are other ways to achieve this. All suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: A problem you might run into is `run_check` is always "out of date", so any rule with it as prerequisite will be remade every time, even on no-op. An alternative is to conditionally write version to file and have `run_check` depend on that file.

Comment: @Andreas Is it because the shell commands to get the versions that make `run_check` "out of date"? By conditionally writing version to file, do you mean having OLD_VERSION and NEW_VERSION as the prerequisites of `run_check` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know whether you want to run the tests when you invoke make, before you start to build anything, you can just do this:

```
OLD_VERSION := $(shell COMMAND_TO_RETRIEVE_THE_OLD_VERSION)
NEW_VERSION := $(shell COMMAND_TO_RETRIEVE_THE_NEW_VERSION)
ifneq ($(NEW_VERSION), $(OLD_VERSION))
    CHECK = run-check
else
    CHECK =
endif

build : target1 target2 $(CHECK)
```

> All I want to do is to call a function inside another function in an "if" statement. This feels normal in other languages but seems to be not so common in Makefile.

A makefile is not a programming language.  It's a language for defining a directed acyclic graph.  It's a mistake to think of it like a procedural language where rules are "functions" that you can "call".  That leads you down all sorts of incorrect mental pathways.

A makefile defines a graph: when you run make it will first read all the makefiles to create a representation of that graph in memory.  Then after it's complete, it will *walk* the graph starting at whatever goal target node(s) were given, and operate on those nodes.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! If I were to do it this way, would the else bracket still be necessary? As in, do I still need to assign `CHECK =`? Also just to make sure, if I have the `build : ...` defined before the `CHECK`, it will not work, right? As the variable `$(CHECK)` has not had any value yet?

Comment: The else block is not needed unless you want to enable warnings about unused variables.  Correct, the value must be set before the rule is defined.